# Greasemonkey - change HTML classname

Tags: greasemonkey, tampermonkey

i have a page with multi-div class like this:

```
<div class="fl wid470 adm-leftsection">
```

how can i change all to:

```
<div class="fl wid980">
```

Thanks!

Comment: Any editor will let you do a global search-replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `document.querySelectorAll`. This allows you to select DOM elements with specific attributes/classes.

```
var selected=document.querySelectorAll(".fl.wid470.adm-leftsection");
for(var i = 0, max = selected.length; i < max; i++) {
    all[i].className="fl wid980";
}
```